# Nice name for `decorator' class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to separate the API I'm working on into two sections: 'bare-bones' and 'cushy'. The idea is that all method calls in the 'cushy' section could be expressed in terms of the ones in the 'bare-bones' section, that is, they would only serve as convenience methods for the quick-and-dirty. The reason I would like to do this is that very often when people are beginning to use an API for the first time, they are not interested in details and performance: they just want to get it working.

Anybody tried anything similar before? I'm particularly interested in naming conventions and organizing the code.

Comment: I would avoid the word "decorator", as this is a rather different design pattern. I think this might be called the Facade Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody at work suggested `Foo` and `FooHelper`. I like it.

Comment: `Helper` doesn't tell me much: do I have to have a `Foo`, and then if I need one I can grab a `FooHelper`?  Is it possible to have a `FooHelper` without a `Foo`?

Not to say I haven't used `Helper`s myself, but it doesn't really help me figure out what I should be doing.

Answer (score 3):

One way to provide a discrete separation of 'cushy' vs 'bare-bones' would be using separate interfaces that are implemented by the same class. When writing an API I like to keep it as simple as possible. If you need lots of parameters, consider using a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've done something like this before, and I tend to pre-pend a word that indicates what the extra functionality is doing.

For example, a basic `Vector` class might only perform very basic vector operations (add, dot product), and a `Vectors` class might have a variety of static helper methods (cross products, projections, etc).  Then, a `FluentVector` incorporates all those helper operations, while mutating the underlying `Vector`.

However, this isn't the decorator pattern - decorator produces different "decorated" results with the same interface.  This is the facade pattern - different interface with the same underlying function.

Also, keep in mind that your extended API may have a variety of different ways of delivering the same function.  Back to my `Vector` example, one might not want to mutate the underlying `Vector` with each chained-operation and instead introduce a new `Vector` - this might be an `ImmutableFluentVector` or some such.  The API would be identical, except for the specification of side-effects.  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking for nice names, commonly used is **simple or basic API and extended API**. The simple API uses, as mentioned by  Simon Nickerson, the extended API technically by providing an abstraction. See also [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Barebone provides basic functionality and Cushy provides additional functionality:

```
 
public class Skeleton
{
  public virtual void Info()
  {
  }
}

public class Adorner:Skeleton
{
  private Skeleton _skeleton;

  public Adorner(Skeleton skeleton)
  {
     _skeleton = skeleton;
  }

  public override void Info()
  {
   //apply adorning work
  }
}
```

Skeleton bareBones = new Skeleton();
Adorner cushy = new Adorner(bareBones);